# What are the needed jars to work via RMI with a Jackrabbit repository?

Tags: jackrabbit

What jars are needed to work via RMI with a Jackrabbit repository?

When RMI is used via JcrUtils.getRepository("http://$SERVER_ADDRESS:$PORT/$CONTEXT"), what jars are needed in the classpath to be able to work with all JCR & Jackrabbit features?

Should all Jackrabbit jars be included or can we limit them only to some "interfaces"?

Answer (score 0):

After investigations I have found
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jackrabbit/jackrabbit-jcr-rmi/2.4.3

In concrete I have to add this list of Jars to Eclipce project:

- jcr-2.0.jar
- jackrabbit-jcr-commons-2.4.3.jar
- jackrabbit-jcr-rmi-2.4.3.jar
- logback-classic-1.0.0.jar
- jackrabbit-api-2.4.3.jar
- jackrabbit-core-2.4.3.jar
- slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
- logback-core-1.0.0.jar